# what is dynamic translator buffer?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, gdb

I want to get elf information of executable file at python script

```
from pwn import *

p = process("./rtl")
e = ELF("./rtl")

def slog(name, addr): return success(": ".join([name, hex(addr)]))

buf = b'A'*0x39
p.sendafter("Buf: ", buf)
p.recvuntil(buf)
cnry = u64(b'\x00' + p.recvn(7))
slog('canary', cnry)
```

then entered command

```
$cat rtl.py
```

I get a message

```
Could not allocate dynamic translator buffer
```

this message also printed when I debug using gdb and pwndbg

```
pwndbg: loaded 157 pwndbg commands and 43 shell commands. Type pwndbg [--shell | --all] [filter] for a list.
pwndbg: created $rebase, $ida gdb functions (can be used with print/break)
Reading symbols from rtl...
(No debugging symbols found in rtl)
------- tip of the day (disable with set show-tips off) -------
The $heap_base GDB variable can be used to refer to the starting address of the heap after running the heap command
pwndbg> start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x4011de

Temporary breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004011de in main ()
Could not allocate dynamic translator buffer
```

I need to debug with x86 intel architecture, but my laptop is m1 macbook.
So I'm using amazon ec2 ubuntu-server cli free tier.

How can I resolve the allocate buffer problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem using the `ELF` command on a small Digital Ocean droplet with only 512MB of memory.

I believe the underlying issue is that `ELF` uses unicorn, which includes a call to `mmap` for 1073741824 bytes. This errors out and prints the error message you received above. This issue is documented in some unicorn GitHub issues, [including this one](https://github.com/unicorn-engine/unicorn/issues/508).

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/unicorn/lib/libunicorn.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
read(6, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \242;\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(6, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=24125584, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 22447520, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 6, 0) = 0x7fd989a00000
mmap(0x7fd989d9c000, 13496320, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 6, 0x39c000) = 0x7fd989d9c000
mmap(0x7fd98aa7b000, 3039232, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 6, 0x107b000) = 0x7fd98aa7b000
mmap(0x7fd98ad61000, 1601536, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 6, 0x1360000) = 0x7fd98ad61000
mmap(0x7fd98aee8000, 525728, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd98aee8000
close(6)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fd98ad61000, 1064960, PROT_READ) = 0
brk(0x560dbea2a000)                     = 0x560dbea2a000
mmap(NULL, 1073741824, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
write(2, "Could not allocate dynamic trans"..., 45Could not allocate dynamic translator buffer
) = 45
```

Try upgrading your RAM or moving to a development environment with more memory. For me, upgrading to the 4GB Digital Ocean droplet solved this issue.

You can also test to ensure this is the root cause by compiling and running the following script. If it completes without error then your environment should be sufficient for the `ELF` command.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main() {
    printf("Trying big mmap\n");
    void* ptr = mmap(NULL, 1073741824, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if ((MAP_FAILED == ptr) && (errno == ENOMEM)) {
        printf("ERROR: check memory\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use memory swap and allocate sufficent memory, I had same issue on my ncp instance and I fiexd it by using memory swap

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).